# cakephp: How to load Flash component in the plugin?

Tags: plugins, cakephp-3.0

I am using `CakePHP 3` and add a plugin `cakphp-Notifier`.

I want to add flash component in that plugin.
how to add cakephp default component in plugin?

**Code:**

**NotificationManager.php**

```php
use Cake\Controller\Component\FlashComponent;
class {
    // ...
    private $Flash;
        public function __construct( )
        {
            $this->Flash = new FlashComponent();
        }
    // ...
    public function send {
    $smsAPI->sendSms($numbers, $message, $sender);
    $this->Flash->success(__('SMS sent .'));
    // ...
}
```

I got this error:

> Required parameter $registry missing.
>   Invocation parameters types are not compatible with declared.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should tell us what you already tried and what is not working.

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis, Thanks. I edited.

Comment: format edit with mark error and separate information of question

Answer (score 1):

First you must import the component on the top of your plugin file:

```
use Cake\Controller\Component\FlashComponent;
```

Then import the component inside your Class

```
var $components = array('Flash');
```

Then use your Flash functions

```
$this->Flash->set(__('Error!'));
```

Hope it works!